# Simulating a "spark gap" in PSPICE

Tags: voltage, spark

The details of this project are too long, so I am not going to bore you guys with them. What I am trying to do is to get the voltage across the right-hand side of the circuit to reach its highest and then drop abruptly to near zero. 
But what's happening is that it reaches its peak and then stays at that level (essentially, a voltage clamp). The Zeners are used to clamp the voltage at that level but I somehow need to drop it abruptly right after it peaks. Any suggestions? [image: circuit diagram][image: simulation output]

Comment: So the zeners and resistors are doing their job and clamping the voltage. You don't want the output clamped. The conclusion is that you should get rid of them. Or at least cut R1 down to about 1 ohm.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to observe and how you came up with this model for the spark gap.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast If I take out the zeners, or even lower their breakdown voltage, the simulation does not converge. And the inductor acts as a short so the value of the resistor wouldn't matter.

Comment: @FL_Engineer This is based on Basso's spark gap model. I am trying to simulate his model and once it works I will change it to meet the specifications of my spark gap

Comment: He is talking about http://www.intusoft.com/nlhtm/nl50.htm#SPARKGAPMODELING It's not clear how you've configured your "zener_spark" since that's not shown in your schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a Shockley diode or DIAC model (NOT a Schottky diode).  A Shockley diode turns on when the voltage across it reaches its breakdown voltage and doesn't turn off until the current though it falls below a minimum holding current level.

Here's a site that goes through creating a SPICE model: http://www.beigebag.com/case_shockley.htm